# Is `orphan_types` the only way to specify possible resolve types for an interface?

Tags: graphql-ruby

The `ruby-graphql` documentation says the following about resolve types for interfaces:

> ...a schema finds it types by traversing its fields, starting with `query`, `mutation` and `subscription`. If an object is *never* the return type of a field, but only connected via an interface, then it must be explicitly connected to the schema via `orphan_types`.

*[See here](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/guides/type_definitions/interfaces.md)*

I have the following definition of a module with two classes that implement it:

```
module Contact
  include GraphQL::Schema::Interface

  field :id, ID, null: false
end

class Cmpany < Types::Base
  implements Contact

  graphql_name "Company"

  field :name, String, null: false
end

class Person < Types::Base
  implements Contact

  graphql_name "Person"

  field :first_name, String, null: false
  field :last_name, String, null: false
end
```

As it stands, my code matches the description in the documentation, in that the types `Company` and `Person` are *never* the return type of any field in the schema other than the query which has the interface `Contact` as its return type. Without any other changes, GraphQL does not recognize the `contacts` query.

Is `orphan_types` to interfaces what `possible_types` is to unions? Perhaps it's the naming that puts me off, but `orphan_types` seems like a workaround that shouldn't be used. Is it the correct solution?